# Is this a float charger or trickle charger?

Tags: battery-charging, charger

Below is a simple charging circuit using LM317 and BC547 and it is mostly classified as a float charger in many forums. This seems to reduce the current flow when the battery is fully charged, however does not turn off the charger completely. Hence can this be connected to SLA batteries indefinitely without affecting the battery life? or is this a trickle charger, which should be disconnected after charging.

By definition float charger will only turn on and charge your battery when it has self-discharged below a certain level, whereas a trickle charger continuously emits a small current of electricity regardless of the charge level or even if it's full. It is also mentioned that for SLA batteries, a float charger could be connected indefinitely where as the trickle chargers needs to be disconnected after charging.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyMFvN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Updated components as per recommendation**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8dkrM.png)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When no battery is connected the circuit operates as a constant-voltage source having an output voltage of \$\mathrm{V_o=11\cdot 1.25V = 13.75VDC}\$ with zero current flow.

When a battery is connected, if the battery voltage is less than, say, 12V then the circuit will work as a constant-current source having a constant output current of \$\mathrm{I_o[A]=V_{BE-BC547}[mV]/470\approx1.5[A]}\$.

During the battery is charging the battery voltage will rise up to a point that the D1 gets reverse biased *(Note: Charge current may drop as the battery voltage increases, but I'm not sure about that)*. So the circuit will switch its operating mode from constant current to constant voltage with zero current flow **even if the battery is not removed**.

So, this circuit fits in your "float charger" definition:

> float charger will only turn on and charge your battery when it has self-discharged below a certain level

**PS:** The circuit may not work with 15V source since the LM317 requires a minimum difference of 3V between the input and output. For a source voltage of 18VDC and an output current of 1.5A, the LM317 will dissipate at least 7.5W. I'm sure you know what that means.

Comment: Will it really reach zero current flow? Can it be connected to the battery indefinitely? If so, this seems to be a better solution than those with relay cutoff, provided we use a voltage regulator with least drop out (eg. MIC29302) and a schottky diode.

Comment: `Will it really reach zero current flow?` The diode guarantees this. `Can it be connected to the battery indefinitely?` It seems so.

Comment: The diode is actually added to stop current from battery flowing back to the circuit when the power supply is turned off. Wouldn't the diode fail or heats up when current is applied from both sides?

Comment: @Zacson `The diode is actually added to stop current from battery flowing back to the circuit when the power supply is turned off.` True but not that only. What if the battery voltage gets high enough (e.g. 13.7VDC)? Can the current flow? `Wouldn't the diode fail or heats up when current is applied from both sides?` How can you apply current to a diode from both sides? Side note *(I forgot to mention in my answer)*: 1N4007 is a terrible choice for this application since the current can be as high as 1.5A when a fully drained battery is connected. A Schottky diode with low Vf should be used.

Comment: Sorry, it is voltage applied from both sides. I shall update the diagram with better components. Though this circuit is simple, cheap and effective, why do we find many or most SLA chargers in the market using a relay cutoff? Apart from the heat generated, does it have other drawbacks?

Comment: I hope this chargers also allows the load(lighter loads consuming much lesser current that the charger) to be connected directly to the battery, which is an added advantage over cutoff circuits!

Comment: @Zscson IDK why the others use relay cutoff, but I'm sure there are semiconductor-based circuits available in the market. I don't see an extra drawback other than heat. By the way, heat is very important here since the regulator dissipates very much power. For 1.5A load current you may not be able to cool it down. The charger can also drive light loads with CV. Shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I have updated the circuit in my question with better components (LDO & Schottky) having very low dropout voltage. And now it can work with 15V supply I guess, which also means lesser heat? Does it now qualify to be a better solution with lower heat at 1.5A?

Comment: Heat is directly proportional to the voltage difference between input and output: The lesser the difference, the lesser the heat.

Comment: Shouldn't we consider the LDO and diode drop for calculation? If so with a 15V power supply, the regulator must be dropping 1V or less at 1.4A which would be less than1.5W rite? Also I hope such current is passed only when the battery is depleted.

Comment: @Zacson true. Multiply the dissipation by Rth(j-a) which is given in the datasheet and you'll have temperature rise. Add it to ambient temp and you have final junction temp. Be sure it does not reach max allowable junction temp. About the current, yes, the current "may" decrease as the battery gets charged. I'm not sure about that. Maybe you should simulate the circuit before building.